# Adding an element to an existing XML

Tags: xslt

I'm not really into XSLT and to have an app work i need to modify an existing XML but don't know how to do it. I'm sure it's not that hard but i don't understand much how this thing work so far and i'm a bit in a hurry.

So the XML looks like this

```
    <Culture id="uc_dummy">
        <notable_and_wanderer_templates>
            <template name="NPCCharacter.spc_wanderer_empire_0" />
        </notable_and_wanderer_templates>
    </Culture>
```

and i want it to look like this

```
    <Culture id="uc_dummy">
        <notable_and_wanderer_templates>
            <template name="NPCCharacter.spc_wanderer_empire_0" />
            <template name="NPCCharacter.uc_wanderer_empire_0" />
        </notable_and_wanderer_templates>
    </Culture>
```

And of course there are more than one  block with different ID in the file and i want only this one to be altered, also using  as an element seem to be confusing for XSLT as it's a keyword for this language ...

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you are in a hurry, I would advise agaist using a technology that you don't have time to learn properly. Using technologies you don't understand always costs you more time than it saves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Culture[@id='uc_dummy']/notable_and_wanderer_templates">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <template name="NPCCharacter.uc_wanderer_empire_0" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There is no problem with using `template` as element name, because when you use it as an instruction it is prefixed by `xsl` so it's in the [XSLT namespace.](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#xslt-namespace)